# Properly combining formulas in the same cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I combine two formulas in the same cell

=SUM(D1/C1*100+100) It yields 87.5
The problem is I want to round this number up but as a percentage.  How do I round up as a percentage all in the same cell?

Comment: `=ROUND(SUM(D1/C1*100+100),0)` should do the trick

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Please don't post answers as comments.

Comment: You mean Round decimal number as percentage ?

Answer (score 2):

First, let me explain that the `SUM()` function adds up a list of numbers or a range of cells.  To use it, you supply a list of numbers (or cell references) separated by commas:

`=SUM (number1, [number2], [number3], ...)`

Your formula isn't really using the SUM() function, because this expression

`=D1/C1*100+100`

gives the same answer.  But no matter, your formula is (almost) giving you the answer that you want, so let's work with what you have.
**___________________________________________________________________________**

I think you're saying that your formula gives an answer of `87.5`, but you want the answer to show as `88%`.  It's pretty easy to do that.

First, modify your formula to divide your answers by 100:

`=SUM(D1/C1*100+100)/100`

This changes the `87.5` to `0.875`.  Next, round to the number of decimal places that you want (as suggested by @cyber):

`=ROUND(SUM(D1/C1*100+100)/100,2)`

This rounds your answer to 2 decimal places, giving `0.88`.  If you change the 2 in the formula to a 1, it will round to 1 decimal place, giving `0.9`.

Finally, use the Format > Cells... menu to format the cells containing your answer as percentages.  Choose 0 decimal places, and the answer will show as `88%` (or `90%` if you rounded to 1 decimal place).

Also note that (as @Blackwood points out) this last formula can be greatly simplified to:

`=ROUND(D1/C1+1,2)`

Comment: Good explanation. I realise that you are trying to stay as close as possible to the OP's formula, but wouldn't `ROUND(D1/C1+1,2)` be simpler?

Comment: Sure. I didn't want to make things too complicated.  But that's a good point, and I'll add it as a suggestion.

Answer (score -2):

You may use this formula also: `=FLOOR(SUM(A2/B2*100+100),1)`

Suppose `A2 has 25 & B2 has 50` then you get `150`.

Then after select the Cell.

Click Cell Format & select Custom.

From the Type Select `0`, you find it below General.

Place cursor next to it and edit it like 0"%".

Now `150` will looks like `150%`.

**Note,** if you use ROUND function as suggested above in comments by   cybernetic.nomad then also you need to apply the Custom Format because, if you apply Percentage cell format your value will look like `15000%`

**Edited:** If you want to round the value UP then you may use these Formulas:

```
=ROUNDUP(SUM(A2/B2*100+100),0)
```

or

```
=CEILING(SUM(A2/B2*100+100),1)
```

**Note,** finally if you want 150 to look like 150% (in percentage Format) then ultimately you need to apply the **Custom Format** as I've describer above. If you apply **Percentage Format** even when decimal value will set as 0, the value will appear like 15000%

*Since you have not disclosed those 2 values which have yielded 87.5 so that I've assumed any two and genuinely those two numbers could be any combination.*

Suppose you don't want to use the Formula as you have shown above and your only intention is to ROUND-UP the 87.5 to 88 independently then you may use,

```
=ROUNDUP(C2,0) or =CEILING(C2,1)
```

*BUt, don't forget to apply the Custom Format otherwise 88 wiill appear as 8800%.*